Can't set className attribute for SVG component
During migration from webpack to vite I faced the following issue. I have the following React component:
import { otherQuote as other__quote } from '@styles/pages/product/other/other.module.scss';
import {
  quote,
  quoteText as quote__text,
  quoteAuthor as quote__author,
  quoteIcon as quote__icon,
} from '@styles/pages/product/other/quote.module.scss';
import { productRectangle as product__rectangle } from '@styles/pages/product/product.module.scss';
import cn from 'classnames';
import QuotationMark from '@assets/quotationMark.svg';

const Quote = () => {
  return (
    <section className={cn(other__quote, quote, product__rectangle)}>
      <QuotationMark className={quote__icon} /> {/*<--- erorr */}
      <q className={quote__text}>
        ...
      </q>
      <footer className={quote__author}>...</footer>
    </section>
  );
};

export { Quote };

When I try to set className attribute to QuotationMark svg component, typescript generates the following error:

TS2322: Type { className: string; } is not assignable to type IntrinsicAttributes
Property className does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes

I have noticed the error occurred when I connected vite's vite/client type declarations file as proposed in vite's reference for env, which in turn contains the following declaration for svg:
declare module '*.svg' {
  const src: string
  export default src
}

p.s. I use svgr plugin which transforms svg into react components
So what could be done here to have ability to add className attribute to svg components?

svgr alone doesn't look like it supports vite. How have you set this up?

@AlexWayne, svgr has parcel support, vite exploits parcel under the hood. I set it as a parcel plugin

I used the following workaround. I augmented *.svg module declaration following way:


/// <reference types="vite/client" />

declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.ComponentProps<'svg'> & { title?: string }
  >;

  export = ReactComponent;
}



